# Как вычислить длину и степень схожести строки

Tags: javascript

Какие функции отвечают за данные операции?

В php знаю strlen и similar_text. Но нужно на js.
Степень схожести в %.
Длину в количестве символов или байтов.

Comment: Вот здесь отлично описано про длину строки - [Базовые типы: Строки, Числа, Boolean](http://javascript.ru/basic/types).

Answer (score -1):

Длина определяется через .length
Встроенной функции для определения степени схожести нет, но, возможно, это поможет:
http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/